# Error in inv(A) : could not find function "inv"

Tags: r

*** It's related to R
I want to take inverse of A (matrix) by inv(). Which package from what library should i install ?

Little code is as follows,

```
A <- matrix( c(5, 1, 0,
               3,-1, 2,
               4, 0,-1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
det(A)

(AI  <- inv(A))
```

Comment: If you google "matrix inversion r" you get this as the top hit: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matlib/vignettes/inv-ex1.html. From there you can see **matlib** is the package you want, so install it (needed once only) then make it avalable with library() like this `install.packages("matlib")` then `library(matlib)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the inverse of a matrix in R, use the `solve` function.

See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/solve

```
A <- matrix( c(5, 1, 0,
               3,-1, 2,
               4, 0,-1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
solve(A)
```

gives the output

```
       [,1]    [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 0.0625  0.0625  0.125
[2,] 0.6875 -0.3125 -0.625
[3,] 0.2500  0.2500 -0.500
```

Answer (score 1):

I typed "inv function r" into Google. First result was `pracma` package:

```
library('pracma')
A <- matrix( c(5, 1, 0,
                3,-1, 2,
                4, 0,-1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
det(A)
[1] 16
(AI  <- inv(A))
       [,1]    [,2]   [,3]
[1,] 0.0625  0.0625  0.125
[2,] 0.6875 -0.3125 -0.625
[3,] 0.2500  0.2500 -0.500
```

Comment: No need for a package, because base R already has the `solve` function.

Comment: OP asked for a package that contains `inv` function not for a way to inverse a matrix

Comment: Yes, solve() did the work. But thanks for responding and trying to help. I really appreciate that.